# Why am I getting different public ip from two computers on the same local network

Tags: ip, lan

This is a network setup in a lab of academic institution
PC1: Connected to wired LAN socket of Lab. Connection is DHCP.

> IP: 10.21.106.221
>  Netmask: 255.255.252.0
>  Default Route:
>   10.21.107.254
>  Broadcast: 10.21.107.255
>  Primary DNS: 10.24.0.193
>  Secondary DNS: 10.24.0.194
>  IP shown on www.whatismyip.com: 14.139.160.237

A wireless router is connected to another LAN socket of the same lab (hopefully of same network). IP allotted to router through DHCP is

> IP: 10.21.106.76
>  Netmask: 255.255.252.0
>  Default Gateway:
>   10.21.107.254
>  DHCP Server : 10.24.4.7
>  DNS Server : 10.24.0.193, 10.24.0.194

Router LAN settings are

> Router IP: 10.0.0.1
>  Netmask: 255.255.255.0

PC2 is getting internet through wireless router. IP settings received by PC2 are

> ip: 10.0.0.7
>  Mask: 255.255.255.0
>  Gateway: 10.0.0.1
>  IP
>   shown on www.whatismyip.com: 14.139.160.242

As per my understanding, I should see the same ip on www.whatismyip.com from both PC, but this is not the case here.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks not under your direct control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

An academic institution is typically large enough to have several outgoing firewalls if not Internet connections.  This particular institution appears to have a /24 of public address space.

It appears that this one sends wireless traffic out of a different interface than wired.  This is not unusual: either for simple convenience or for prioritising bandwidth for a given set of users.

Sometimes you see networks where the outgoing IP address changes per connection, or is different for UDP and TCP.  It's all up to the whim of what the controller of the network thinks is a good idea, usually for bandwidth management, anti-abuse, and security purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have good knowledge of networking but I get your point to some extent. Is there any method/command to know what range of local IPs will correspond to same public ip?

Comment: No, it's just whatever those in charge of a network have chosen.